# WPF: How do I prevent users from entering text in a Textbox data bound to a numeric property?

Tags: wpf, binding

WPF: How do I prevent users from entering text in a Textbox data bound to a numeric property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard validation will handle this...

You can also use a Behavior or attached property to override TextBox's input to prevent non-numeric numbers from being entered.  Here is a [sample behavior that does this](http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2009/10/silverlight-behaviors-and-triggers_07.html).

Comment: I like the phrase "standard validation". Where can I learn more about this?

Comment: Here's a good article on validation in WPF: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpfvalidation.aspx

Comment: @Jonathan: Just realize that the "standard" way of validating in WPF is to let them type in Text, but show an error.  By using a behavior, you can make it so they can't type in text to begin with...

Comment: I understand, but I figure knowing both options will be important in the long run.