# textbox text bound to viewmodel property - detect view's invalid data state

Tags: wpf, validation, xaml, data-binding, mvvm

i have a view with a textbox bound to a double property in a viewodel. WPF or MVVM or whatever is nice enough to display a visual indication to the user (red box around control) when they enter invalid data in the textbox. invalida data in this case means data that can't be converted to a double and syncronized with the viewmodel's property.

what i want to do is detect when the view's controls have data that causes them to no longer be binding. i know i could [limit what the user can type in via code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329177/wpf-how-do-i-prevent-users-from-entering-text-in-a-textbox-data-bound-to-a-nume), but i'm not sure i want to do that.

i also know that i could create a controls data validation method that would validate that all controls are of the required data type, but i would rather not do that unless i have to.

is there a smart and easy way to tell xaml to disallow user input that would cause binding issues?

what is the textbox's binding property whose state causes the red box around the control, or better yet how can i get at the text box's failed binding status?

is there a sweeping call i could make to an entire view/window/layout/panel that would recursively check all bindings to ensure their data is sync'ed with the viewmodel and therefore valid, or some objects are out of sync and invalid, or just binding isn't happening due to invalidity of some of the bound data?

a thought occurs to me just now. if the viewmodel is built for the view, should i be making strings of properties like height and width? to be valid they must be doubles, but these are values the user can type. this would allow me to validate the property in the same way i validate the rest of the object state.

my final revelation aside, anyone have some hot tips on the questions i have here?

Thanks pros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i use string type for my properties and the IDataErrorInfo to check the input. the good thing is there are no binding exceptions and the view and the viewmodel are always in sync.

nevertheless you can also use a maskedbehaviour for your controls, so the user can just input values which raise no bindingerror.

Comment: Looks like this combination of tactics is the most robust solutoin. i didn't know about IDataErrorInfo!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ValidationRules. Then in you class of validation perform your condition if the value is string or numeric.